# Control updated frame in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am getting the below error after the webpage has updated.
"Element is no longer valid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"
The page has a frameset.
frame1 and frame2 are under the frameset. 
Search inquiry was performed on frame1 and result has updated on frame2. 
Once the result has updated, it seems HTML has updated.
When I tried to switch from frame1 to frame2. No such a frame is existing.

Here is the things that I tried.
1. switchTo() by name and frame index # (doesn't work)
2. navigate().refresh() (lost result on frame2)

How can I get control for the newly updated frame2 by Selenium?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess:

Before switching from `frame1` to `frame2` you need to switch to default content using `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

---

From the exception it looks like you tried to use element which was changed and/or no longer exists.

Check the algorithm:
 1. Find `frame1`
 2. Switch to `frame1`
 3. Do actions inside `frame1`
 4. Switch to default content
 5. Find `frame2`
 6. Switch to `frame2`
 7. Get information inside `frame2`

Note:

- on each `Find *` step use explicit wait in order to be sure that it's not a waiting issue.
- make sure that you find `frame2` (step 5) after actions inside `frame1` (step 3)

Explicit wait doc: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits

Comment: Hi drets, thank you for the answer, but I already tried it. It gave me the same error. Tried defaultContent(), parentFrame(), and activeElement(). None of them worked. :(

Comment: You cannot share link to page or/and your code, right?

Comment: I wish I can share. It is work related website so that no one can access the page except its employee who got permission. T-T

Comment: DOM Explorer Tree
<frameset>
<frame1> ... </frame1>
<frame2> ... </frame2>
</frameset>

I have used the following steps:
1. Get url
2. List<WebElement> frames (when I print all of the frame, I see frame2)
3. Switch to frame1 by frame index #
4. Do actions inside of frame1
5. Site from the browser only updating result portion, but DOM Explorer tree refreshes.
Tried the following steps:
1. After do action inside of frame1, it seems entire DOM has been staled.
2. Switch to default content (no frame existing error)
3. Switch to frame2 by frame index # (no frame existing error)

Comment: your algorithm has Find frame1 before switch to... would it be impact this? 
Is there any ways to update driver.get(url) without refresh? (refresh will make disappear result in frame2)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully get you. Selenium updates the DOM automatically, you don't need to refresh anything. Just to make sure that you are using object which refers to the last version of web element in the DOM (i.e. find the element and do something immediately using this object).

Comment: drets, I had the same algorithm with you but didn't included explicit waits. After added it on every single lines, it works!! Thank you for the attention and make me think again! :)

Comment: Oops sorry, Since my reputation is less than 15, I have to be above the level to vote! :(

Comment: Yep I realised it, I'll do you +5 ;-)